# If the same URL can serve different content types shoud Vary include accept?

Tags: rest, http, caching, content-negotiation, vary

If the same URL can serve different content types for the same resource, must Vary include Accept ? Or do browser caches and proxies understand it as being implicit ?

Example:

```
GET /some/thing HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
```

This response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Vary: Transfer-Encoding

{...}
```

or this one

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Vary: Transfer-Encoding, Accept

{...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) does not indicate any kind of "implict" or special treatment of the content type (Accept) header...

> A Vary field value consisting of a comma-separated list of names
> indicates that the named request header fields, known as the
> selecting header fields, might have a role in selecting the
> representation.